# Argument of \ttl@gmk has an extra }. \begin{thebibliography}{112}

Tags: bibliographies, errors, bibliographystyle

I have this errors that is making me mad:

`Argument of \ttl@gmk has an extra }. \begin{thebibliography}{112}`

and then also

`Paragraph ended before \ttl@gmk was complete. \begin{thebibliography}{112}`.

There is clearly something wrong with computing the bibliography. However, I checked all the bibliography entries in the `references.bib` file and everything seems ok.
I also checked all the `\cite{}` calls in my tex file, and also here everything seems ok.

If I don't print the bibliography with the command `\bibliography{references}` there are no errors.

I use texstudio and overleaf. Both give me the same errors. However, overleaf produces the final pdf, while texstudio doesn't. In the file pdf I don't see any issue.

Below my `main.tex` file

```
\documentclass{NSF}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\definecolor{amber}{rgb}{1.0, 0.75, 0.0}
\definecolor{palegold}{rgb}{0.9, 0.75, 0.54}

% BT: this file has a bunch of useful macros:
\input{BT_commands.tex}
% BT: this file holds journal abbreviations:
\input{journals.tex}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\setlength{\bibsep}{2.0pt}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}%anything smaller than 4pt looks bad
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,font=footnotesize]{caption}
\captionsetup{width=.99\textwidth}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{comment}

\newcommand\gamornet{G\textsc{a}M\textsc{or}N\textsc{et}}
\newcommand\gamornettwo{G\textsc{a}M\textsc{or}N\textsc{et}II}

\begin{document}
\title{\Large Title}

\newsection{B}
\vspace{-0.2in}
\input{sections/summary}

% C. Table of Contents 
% A Table of Contents is automatically generated for the proposal by FastLane

% D. Project Description
\newpage\newsection{C}
\input{sections/description}

% E. References Cited
\newpage\newsection{D}

\bibliography{references}
\clearpage


% G. Budget Justification
\newpage\newsection{F}
\input{sections/budget}

\newpage\newsection{F}
\input{sections/budget_CMU}


% I. Facilities, Equipment and Other Resources
\newpage\newsection{G}
\input{sections/resources}

% J. Special Information and Supplementary Documentation
\newpage\newsection{I}
\input{sections/data}       % Data Management Plan (Required)

\newpage\newsection{J}
\input{sections/SuggestedReviewers} 

\newpage
\input{sections/ReviewersNotToInclude} 

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
If I comment out the `\input{}` lines, I got the same error.
Example of bib entries:

```
@ARTICLE{assef2018,
       author = {{Assef}, R.~J. and {Stern}, D. and {Noirot}, G. and {Jun}, H.~D. and
         {Cutri}, R.~M. and {Eisenhardt}, P.~R.~M.},
        title = "{The WISE AGN Catalog}",
      journal = {\apjs},
     keywords = {galaxies: active, infrared: general, quasars: general, Astrophysics - Astrophysics of Galaxies, Astrophysics - Cosmology and Nongalactic Astrophysics},
         year = 2018,
        month = feb,
       volume = {234},
       number = {2},
          eid = {23},
        pages = {23},
          doi = {10.3847/1538-4365/aaa00a},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
       eprint = {1706.09901},
 primaryClass = {astro-ph.GA},
       adsurl = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2018ApJS..234...23A},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}


@article{Hausen2020,
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
arxivId = {1906.11248},
author = {Hausen, Ryan and Robertson, Brant E.},
doi = {10.3847/1538-4365/ab8868},
eprint = {1906.11248},
issn = {0067-0049},
journal = {The Astrophysical Journal Supplement Series},
keywords = {Computational methods,Convolutional neural networks,Extragalactic astronomy,GPU computing,Galaxies,Galaxy classification systems},
month = {may},
number = {1},
pages = {20},
publisher = {American Astronomical Society},
title = {{ Morpheus : A Deep Learning Framework for the Pixel-level Analysis of Astronomical Image Data }},
url = {https://doi.org/10.3847/1538-4365/ab8868},
volume = {248},
year = {2020}
}
```

And the document class NSF is the following `NSF.cls` file

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{NSF}
\LoadClass[11pt, letterpaper, times, onecolumn]{article}

\RequirePackage[margin=1.02in]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[pdftex,colorlinks,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black,filecolor=black]{hyperref}

\RequirePackage{threeparttable}
\RequirePackage{booktabs, caption, makecell}
\RequirePackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps,.pdf,.jpeg,.png}

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} 

\RequirePackage{titlecaps}
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0pt}{\titlecap{#1}\\\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\titlecap{#1}}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\titlecap{#1}}
%\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0.5em}{0.3pt}
%\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0.35em}{0pt}
%\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0.25em}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\begin{center}\LARGE\bfseries{#1}\end{center}}

% Reset page numbering to 1.  This is helpful, since the text can only
% be 15 pages (unless otherwise specified, see individual solicitations), 
% and reviewers will want to believe we've kept it within those limits
\newcommand{\newsection}[1]{\pagenumbering{arabic}\renewcommand{\thepage}{#1--\arabic{page}}}
```

Comment: Where does documentclass `NSF` comes from? Do you have a link to it? Please add two bib entries to your question and make it compilable for us (we do not have your `\input`ed files ...). And no, I did not downvote ...

Comment: Your `main.tex` doesn't show the problem that you describe. The only errors are those about files not found. If you need help, please show code that produces the error.

Comment: @Mensch thanks, I updated the question with the .cls file and showed two bib entries. The input files are very long files, is there a way to know if the problem is in them? if I comment the `\input` lines, I got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message `Argument of \ttl@gmk has an extra }` comes from used package `titlesec` or better the error is caused from command `\titleformat`.

If you comment all this commands like that:

```
\RequirePackage{titlecaps}
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
%\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection}{0pt}{\titlecap{#1}\\\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
%\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{0pt}{\titlecap{#1}}
%\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{0pt}{\titlecap{#1}}
%%\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0.5em}{0.3pt}
%%\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0.35em}{0pt}
%%\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0.25em}{0pt}
```

in your class `NFS` the document compiles with one correct error (missing definition for `\apjs`) to the following bibliography:

[image: resulting bibliography]

Because I do not use package `titlesec` I can not help you searching the error but for me it seems to come from your used `\titlecap{#1}` in `\titleformat` ...

Comment: Thank you so much! Commenting out the `\titleformat` the error is gone!